# How do I access a variable of controller from html source in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, html

I have something like this in my app.js

```
.controller('DishDetailController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

        var dish={
                      name:'Piaza',
                      image: 'images/piaza.png'
        }
        $scope.dish = dish;
 }])
```

Then when I access from html like:

```
 <div ng-controller="DishDetailController">
     <p>{{dish.name}}</p>
 </div>
```

But this doesn't seem to work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Show your HTML - dou you have a ng-controller statement or a directive using this controller somewhere?

Comment: Just showed my html there, I included '-' before html tags for it to appear here...

Comment: I edited it - you do not need to include anything to show the html... (You do not have them in your real code right?!)

Comment: Your code doesn't say anything about the possible bug, I mean that you need to check in what module the DishDetailController is registered... 
for example: angular.module('my-module', []) and in html ng-app="my-module"...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/20951/

Thats a working exampple of what you should have, so you are doing something wrong and not showing us your entire code. try creating a fiddle with your problem.

Comment: Ah stupid me, Sorry everyone. Read permissions...

Answer (score -2):

No, Everything is fine but the problem is in your app.js file.

I know it will work if you comment out this line :

> // "The date property of your JavaScript object holding the comment" =
>   new Date().toISOString();

:)